# prevent secrets from being printed to cloud-init logs

Tags: bash, rhel, amazon-linux, cloud-init

A `cloud-init` script needs to set environment variable values to contain secrets.

> **What specific syntax can be changed in the below to prevent the secret `PASS` and `PSS` from being printed in the `cloud-init` logs?**

**CURRENT CODE:**

Here is an example of a section of a cloud-init script that is causing secrets to be written into the log files:

```
export PASS=$PSS
echo "export PASS='$PSS'" >> /etc/environment
echo "export PASS='$PSS'" >> /etc/bashrc
echo "export PASS='$PSS'" >> /etc/profile
```

**THE PROBLEM:**

The problem is that the current code shown above is printing the explicit values contained in the variables into the cloud-init logs.  This means that, currently, the only way to protect the secrets is to lock down the logs and be hyper-vigilant about rotating secrets as much as possible.

**WHAT WE NEED:**

> **Is there a linux-native way to prevent secrets from being printed into the output and logs?**

We would like this to be agnostic with respect to tool and agnostic with respect to cloud.    Meaning that we would like to avoid relying on a pipeline tool's secret obfuscation features, and we would also like for the secrets to be obscured whether this is running in AWS, or Azure, or any other cloud provider.  We would like a linux/bash solution to this problem that is portable and agnostic.

We use RHEL-based images for all our linux instances, including pure-RHEL, and also including Amazon Linux 2 and CentOS.

**RESPONSES TO COMMENTS**

Per `@falcajr`'s questions, the cloud-init script begins with `#!/bin/bash` and the problem persists whether or not `set -e` is present in the script.  The logs we are seeing the secrets in are the console output when the cloud init script runs, which no doubt is already stored someplace, and which we will have to store separately in our own automation system.  This OP asks for a linux-native solution so that it should not matter where the destination is.  For example if there were an `obscureFromOutput()` function, we would be asking for something like the following except in valid syntax and not in the following made up pseudocode:

```
echo "export PASS='obscureFromOutput($PSS)'" >> /etc/environment
```

Per `@Isaac`'s comment, the `PSS` is received as an input variable for the cloud-init script.  We do not believe that it should matter that packer is currently the tool sending in the `PSS` input variable because we would like a linux-native solution that will work just as well if we switch to `ARM templates` or to `cloud formation` or to any other tool.  If you have a specific way of solving this problem this OP is requesting a specific solution.

We then tried `@falcojr`'s second suggestion to make each command look as follows, but the secrets are still showing up in the packer command line output which gets pushed into logs:

```
echo "export PASS='$PSS'" >> /etc/environment &> /dev/null
```

Are we using the correct syntax?  Is there something else to try?

Comment: When you say "cloud-init" script, do you mean a (ba)sh script that starts with '#!' or something in a #cloud-config? Which log(s) are you seeing these commands in? Are you sure there's not a "set -e" somewhere in your script?

Comment: @falcojr Please see update to the OP addressing your comment.

Comment: @falcojr This is azure but in AWS I would imagine this would be what goes into `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log`.  I imagine that same output gets piped anywhere it is sent.  For example maybe this might me `stdout` and `stderr`, so this OP might be asking can `stdout` and `stderr` have secrets obfuscated at the point of the bash interpreter.  Here, an external script is running packer which in turn is receiving `cloud-init` output.  This OP is asking if somehow the bash interpreter that runs any bash script i.e. the `cloud-init` script can be configured to obfuscate anything that is a secret.

Comment: From the perspective of cloud-init, it's just running a script. Nothing should be output to the console (or logs) unless there's a redirect somewhere to capture the stdout/stderr. For individual commands, you could '&> /dev/null".

Comment: @falcojr Thank you.  But please see end of the OP for the results of trying your suggestion.  This is not working yet.

Comment: So this is happening as part of a packer build? Not an instance launch? How is packer invoking cloud-init? Can you post the packer template you're using to build your image?

Answer (score 0):

Could you store and retrieve them from AWS Secrets manager from inside your code instead of placing them statically in the file? You could probably add the permissions to the instance profile so that the servers can retrieve them on boot, store them in a variable, and use them during execution.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just wrap it in a script?

As I understand it the problem is that Amazon is echoing each line to the log, and it's expanding the environment variable before logging.

Wrapping it in a script should force it to log before it expands the environment variable.

I've not tested this (typing from my phone)

```
sh -c "
echo \"export PASS='\$PSS'\" >> /etc/environment
echo \"export PASS='\$PSS'\" >> /etc/bashrc
echo \"export PASS='\$PSS'\" >> /etc/profile
"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `set -x` in your script, then this may solve the issue:

```
# Turn off tracing before any commands with a secret in them.
set +x

export PASS=$PSS
echo "export PASS='$PSS'" >> /etc/environment
echo "export PASS='$PSS'" >> /etc/bashrc
echo "export PASS='$PSS'" >> /etc/profile

# Turn tracing back on after.
set -x
```

Per the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html):

> `-x`
>
> Print a trace of simple commands, `for` commands, `case` commands, `select`
> commands, and arithmetic `for` commands and their arguments or
> associated word lists after they are expanded and before they are
> executed. The value of the `PS4` variable is expanded and the resultant
> value is printed before the command and its expanded arguments.

Edits: Wording and formatting.

Comment: How about only turning `-x` back on if it was on to begin with. Perhaps something like: `save_x=${-//[!x]} ; set +x ; ... ; set -$save_x`

Comment: @MartinKealey I like it however if `x` is NOT set, then `save_x` will be empty resulting in `set -` for the final command which will turn off `x` (a non issue since it's already off) and `v`, if it was on.

So perhaps this would work better:
`save_xv=${-//[!xv]} ; set +x ; ... ; set -$save_xv`

Comment: excellent catch, thankyou